# Launcher Icon appears too small

Tags: android, icons, launcher

I have an icon image at 800x800, it's a circle (transparent corners). I used [that tool](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) to create all the different resolutions for me into `mipmap` folders. I can't understand why the rest of the apps on my phone appear to have bigger icons if I followed the guidelines.

**EDIT:** I think it's the tool that gets rid of at least 10% of my icon and makes it smaller, which is quite annoying but does anyone have another tool that does the same effects to icons? Making it appear folded like Google Calendar for example...?

Also, the `dp unit grid` section of this document confuses me even more - "Android expects product icons to be provided at 48dp..." We have to then scale it? What does this mean? It sounds a bit like `9patch`.

Anyway, here's how my icon looks compared to other apps.

[image: Screenshot]

and my app icon (from xhdpi folder at 96x96):

[image: app icon]

**EDIT**: I had my phone's DPI changed from the CM settings from 320 to 300. However I tried changing back to 320 and restarting phone and reinstalling the app. It was still smaller than others.

Comment: can you post your image. and the device have you tested

Comment: It seems that you image has a padding value...

Comment: I added my icon. I don't know what padding it could have except the padding from the white border to the actual green circle which is a 5% padding setting from the Tool that I linked in my question. I'm using a Moto G xt1032 with CM13 (6.0)

Comment: 48dp = 48 dot per pixel. It's resolution, not size. In order to obtain a good quality icon, the icon should be more than 48dp.

Comment: Remove that 5% padding and try again... Set it to 0%

Comment: The padding is used for the foreground image. Btw, I would suggest you use GIMP to enlarge the icon to solve this problem rather than wasting time here

Comment: if it's already at a 96x96 size for the xhdpi folder what do I enlarge it to? I can see the tool I linked leaves a lot of size unused - it makes the icon smaller, I wonder why they did that...must be outdated or something

Comment: I also face this issue when I try to generate launcher icons from AndroidAssetStudio. So instead I manually resize my icons using gimp.

Comment: I have to try using gimp but what I loved about the AssesStudio wasn't the resizing itself but the effect similar to Google's App icons. It makes them appear folded and more Material-like. Like the Calendar app. See, my icon is a bit similar but only too smal...know of any tools that do the same effect?